# Php, includes of headers and footer

Tags: php

I am building a website , and I'm wondering how can I include a header file, but each page got its own title and some pages even got another css , or javascript. How can I make it organized in my code? , Now i don't want to make wet code, I want to make DRY code that's why I'm asking it

Comment: Make header/footer with variables in it.  Set those variables on your page before doing `include 'file.php';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are surely a variety of approaches and template standards/systems/etc. you could use.  One simple approach might just be to have your included header have a dependency on a variable for the page title:

```
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
```

And then set that variable before including the header:

```
$pageTitle = 'Hello World!';
include('header.php');
```

Any piece of logic for conditionally outputting content, outputting values, etc. can be externalized as a dependency like that.

You might even make the dependencies more explicit by having the included file be a function or object which writes the output, rather than just procedural code that directly writes the output.  That way the function or object could more explicitly advertise the dependencies it requires.  (Which also makes the logic more testable.)

Comment: Hey David, and how can I make some scripts on certain pages?, also this is the best approach?

Comment: @jojo: Either put the scripts in separate includes and conditionally include one or the other, or put them in the same include and conditionally output one script or the other based on a variable.  That variable would then need to be set just like the page title one.

Comment: also one more question, includes act like C pre processor?, or it makes a function call ?

Comment: @jojo: The documentation is generally the best place to look for details on that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php  I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of PHP to state with certainty.

Comment: Thanks you sir for your help, I really appreciate it !, I don't know why people actually downvoted this one, A man asks a simple question.

Comment: @jojo: Neither.  `include` basically takes the contents of the file and "pastes" them into the script at that location.